# Concatenating a tokenized String

Tags: xml, xslt

Say I have the following string in an XML Text node: `Johnson|John|Dr.|Jr.`

I can tokenize this string with the XSLT function `tokenize(...)` (so far so good).
Now I want to format the tokens for presentation, expected result would be: `Dr. John Johnson Jr.`
In case my XML doesn't have all fields, I get a value like `Smith|Will` (blank values are omitted) which I want to present as simply `Will Smith`.

Note that the order of the fields in my formatted representation of the name isn't necessarily the same as the tokenized string.

So I'm looking at `string-join` and `concat`, but can't figure out how to use them without ending up with unnecessary spaces at the end for the blank values.

Comment: what about `normalize-space()` ?

Comment: I'm using that right now (just tried it and it worked), but wanted to know if there was anything to prevent these spaces outright.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the possible order and number of input items and the output order you want, if you have e.g. `<xsl:variable name="seq1" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>` and then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$seq1[3], $seq1[2], $seq1[1], $seq1[4]" separator=" "/>` then you would get `Will Smith` I think.